# How to unit test Soap service access from Crm 2011 Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, dynamics-crm-2011, automated-tests, dynamics-crm

In a Silverlight 5 application in Dynamics CRM 2011 I access the Organization Service of the CRM to query for entity Metadata. I wrote a service that takes an entity name and returns a list of all its fields.

How can I test this service method automatically? The main problem is how to obtain a reference to the organization service from a Silverlight app that does not run in the context of the CRM.

My Service method looks like this:

```
public IOrganizationService OrganizationService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_organizationService == null)
               _organizationService = SilverlightUtility.GetSoapService();
            return _organizationService;
        }
        set { _organizationService = value; }
    }


public async Task<List<string>> GetAttributeNamesOfEntity(string entityName)
    {
        // build request
        OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest
            {
                RequestName = "RetrieveEntity",
                Parameters = new ParameterCollection
                    {
                        new XrmSoap.KeyValuePair<string, object>()
                            {
                                Key = "EntityFilters",
                                Value = EntityFilters.Attributes
                            },
                        new XrmSoap.KeyValuePair<string, object>()
                            {
                                Key = "RetrieveAsIfPublished",
                                Value = true
                            },
                        new XrmSoap.KeyValuePair<string, object>()
                            {
                                Key = "LogicalName",
                                Value = "avobase_tradeorder"
                            },
                        new XrmSoap.KeyValuePair<string, object>()
                            {
                                Key = "MetadataId",
                                Value = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                            }
                    }
            };

        // fire request
        IAsyncResult result = OrganizationService.BeginExecute(request, null, OrganizationService);

        // wait for response
        TaskFactory<OrganizationResponse> tf = new TaskFactory<OrganizationResponse>();
        OrganizationResponse response = await tf.FromAsync(
            OrganizationService.BeginExecute(request, null, null), iar => OrganizationService.EndExecute(result));

        // parse response
        EntityMetadata entities = (EntityMetadata)response["EntityMetadata"];
        return entities.Attributes.Select(attr => attr.LogicalName).ToList();
    }
```

Edit:
I can create and execute unit tests with Resharper and AgUnit. Thus, the problem is not how to write a unit test in general.

Comment: Hi, there is a unit testing framework for Dynamics CRM which allows to do exactly that, and fakes most of the common messages for you. The framework is completely free and available on Git too. Please [check the getting started page](http://dynamicsvalue.com/get-started/overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tweaked the GetSoapService from the standard Microsoft SDK to accept a fall back value. This means no codes changes are needed when debugging in visual studio and running in CRM. Anyway here it is

```
public static IOrganizationService GetSoapService(string FallbackValue = null)
    {
        Uri serviceUrl = new Uri(GetServerBaseUrl(FallbackValue)+ "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web");


        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(Uri.UriSchemeHttps == serviceUrl.Scheme
            ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport : BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

        binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

        binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

        IOrganizationService ser =new OrganizationServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl));

        return ser;


    }

public static string GetServerBaseUrl(string FallbackValue = null)
    {


        try
        {
            string serverUrl = (string)GetContext().Invoke("getClientUrl");
            //Remove the trailing forwards slash returned by CRM Online
            //So that it is always consistent with CRM On Premises
            if (serverUrl.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                serverUrl = serverUrl.Substring(0, serverUrl.Length - 1);
            }

            return serverUrl;
        }
        catch
        {
            //Try the old getServerUrl
            try
            {
                string serverUrl = (string)GetContext().Invoke("getServerUrl");
                //Remove the trailing forwards slash returned by CRM Online
                //So that it is always consistent with CRM On Premises
                if (serverUrl.EndsWith("/"))
                {
                    serverUrl = serverUrl.Substring(0, serverUrl.Length - 1);
                }

                return serverUrl;
            }
            catch
            {
                return FallbackValue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for that proposal. If I understood your approach correctly it deals with providing the URL to the CRM in test scenario and a productive szenario. I tried something similar and my approach resulted in an authentication failure. That makes sense because in the CRM context the authentication context is already there. In my test context it is not.

Comment: I depends on if you are using claims based authentication or normal windows authentication. The windows way will work fine but for claims I think you need to get a "token" from the claims server. I cant be of much help with that as thats not how our CRM is setup

Comment: That is good to know. Now I know where to look at to make it work. Thanks for that hint.