# How to unit test an async method from Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, asynchronous, dynamics-crm-2011

Edit: Context: I write a Silverlight application that accesses a Dynamics CRM 2011 via the Soap Service. I implemented a service for doing this. I want to write a unit test for this service now.

I want to write a unit test for the following method:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetAttributeNamesOfEntity(string entityName)
    {
        // build request
        OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest
        {
            RequestName = "RetrieveEntity",
            Parameters = new ParameterCollection
                {
                    new XrmSoap.KeyValuePair<string, object>()
                        {
                            Key = "EntityFilters",
                            Value = EntityFilters.Attributes
                        },
                    new XrmSoap.KeyValuePair<string, object>()
                        {
                            Key = "RetrieveAsIfPublished",
                            Value = true
                        },
                    new XrmSoap.KeyValuePair<string, object>()
                        {
                            Key = "LogicalName",
                            Value = "avobase_tradeorder"
                        },
                    new XrmSoap.KeyValuePair<string, object>()
                        {
                            Key = "MetadataId",
                            Value = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                        }
                }
        };

        // fire request
        IAsyncResult result = OrganizationService.BeginExecute(request, null, OrganizationService);

        // wait for response
        TaskFactory<OrganizationResponse> tf = new TaskFactory<OrganizationResponse>();
        OrganizationResponse response = await tf.FromAsync(result, iar => OrganizationService.EndExecute(result));

        // parse response
        EntityMetadata entities = (EntityMetadata)response["EntityMetadata"];
        return entities.Attributes.Select(attr => attr.LogicalName).ToList();
    }
```

My first approach was to call the actual CRM. This failed because I cannot authenticate. I asked a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496623/how-to-unit-test-soap-service-access-from-crm-2011-silverlight-application). My second approach is to mock the organization service and run the method against my the mock. Like this:

```
    private bool _callbackCalled = false;
    private SilverlightDataService _service;
    private List<string> names;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        IOrganizationService organizationService = A.Fake<IOrganizationService>();
        _service = new SilverlightDataService {OrganizationService = organizationService};

        IAsyncResult result = A.Fake<IAsyncResult>();
        A.CallTo(organizationService.BeginExecute(A<OrganizationRequest>.Ignored, A<AsyncCallback>.Ignored,
                                                  A<object>.Ignored)).WithReturnType<IAsyncResult>().Returns(result);

        EntityMetadata entities = new EntityMetadata();
        AttributeMetadata meta = new AttributeMetadata();
        meta.LogicalName = "foobar";
        entities.Attributes = new ObservableCollection<AttributeMetadata>();
        entities.Attributes.Add(meta);
        OrganizationResponse response = new OrganizationResponse();
        response.Results = new ParameterCollection();
        response["EntityMetadata"] = entities;


        A.CallTo(() => result.IsCompleted).Returns(true);
        A.CallTo(result.AsyncState).WithReturnType<object>().Returns(response);
        A.CallTo(organizationService.EndExecute(result)).WithReturnType<OrganizationResponse>().Returns(response);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    [Asynchronous]
    public async void TestGetAttributeNamesOfEntity()
    {
        TaskFactory<List<string>> tf = new TaskFactory<List<string>>();
        names = await tf.FromAsync(_service.GetAttributeNamesOfEntity("avobase_tradeorder"), CallbackFunction);

        Assert.IsTrue(_callbackCalled);
        Assert.IsNotNull(names);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// is used as callback for the method GetAttributeNamesOfEntity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<string> CallbackFunction(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        _callbackCalled = true;
        names = (List<string>) result.AsyncState;
        return null;
    }
```

I use FakeItEasy for mocking. When I execute this test (with ReSharper and AgUnit) it waits forever. I also tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513422/silverlight-async-unit-testing), but it did not work.

1) My assumption is that my mocks dont tell the await magic that the task is actually done. Why does the await never end? What do I have to do to fix this?

2) Is there maybe a better approach to do this?

Edit: I am using: VS 2012 Premium, ReSharper 7.1, Silverlight 5, AgUnit 0.7, .Net 4.5, FakeItEasy 1.13.1 installed via NuGet.

Comment: I gather the test method should be an async Task instead of async void.  Also, have you read Skeet's http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/11/25/eduasync-part-17-unit-testing.aspx ?

Comment: Try [FakeXrmEasy](http://dynamicsvalue.com/home), it's a layer on top of FakeItEasy which adds all the mocks for you, where is you'll spend most of the time really. Open source project on git too.